# USB flash disk not showing in file explorer

Tags: flash

I formatted my USB flash drive, its no longer showing in file explorer. I cant see it in Disk management but in Device manager with the exclamation  mark. how can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you disconnect and reconnect it?

Comment: **How** did you format it (what tool did you use)? What file system did you install -- FAT32, the most common for USB drives? What file system shows now in *Disk Management*?

Comment: when i plug in, there is that sound that always come when an external drive is plugged in  but i cant see it in file explorer.

Comment: the first time i plugged in it worked properly but windows popped up an alert that the drive needs formatting. when i ignored it it was working properly but when i plugged in the second time the same pop up came in to format so i just clicked format.

Comment: Disk Manager is showing all the storage partitions i have except this flash disk. i tried a different flash disk on my pc and its working properly.  The device icon is visible under hidden icons on the task bar. When i go to Device Manager i can see it under Universal Serial Buss Controller with the exclamation mark, when i click the device and go to properties there is this error   "This device cannot start. (Code 10)

{Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful.
"

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of hardware failure. You'll need a new flash drive.